# Clojure Can't identify read method of javax.imageio.ImageIO?

Tags: clojure

```
(ns pdf-try.core                                                                                                                            
  (:use clj-pdf.core)                                                                                                                       
  (:require clojure.java.io))                                                                                                               


(defn gen-pdf []                                                                                                                            
 (let [superman (javax.imageio.ImageIO/read "sample_logos/batman.jpeg")                                                                     
       batman (javax.imageio.ImageIO/read  "sample_logos/superman.jpeg")]                                                                   
   (println (new java.util.Date))                                                                                                           
   (pdf [{}  (for [i (range 80000)]                                                                                                         
               (do  [:paragraph                                                                                                             
                   [:image  superman]                                                                                                       
                   [:image batman]]))] "super.pdf")                                                                                         
   (println (new java.util.Date))))                                                                                                         


(defn -main                                                                                                                                 
  "I don't do a whole lot."                                                                                                                 
  [& args]                                                                                                                                  
  (println  "Hello, World!")                                                                                                                
  (gen-pdf))
```

I am getting :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method found: read                                                                                                                              
 What am I missing here ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no such static `read` method which accept `String` as parameter in [`ImageIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) class. Create a File with that path and pass the File as the argument.

```
(defn gen-pdf []                                                                                                                            
 (let [superman (javax.imageio.ImageIO/read "sample_logos/batman.jpeg")                                                                     
       batman (javax.imageio.ImageIO/read  (java.io.File. "sample_logos/superman.jpeg"))]                                                                   
   (println (java.util.Date.))                                                                                                           
   (pdf [{}  (for [i (range 80000)]                                                                                                         
               (do  [:paragraph                                                                                                             
                   [:image  superman]                                                                                                       
                   [:image batman]]))] "super.pdf")                                                                                         
   (println (java.util.Date.))))
```

And, You are wrongly calling Java Class Constructor from Clojure. You need to use like `(Classname. args*)` to call the Java class Constructor from Clojure. For more details, check [clojure-java-interop](http://clojure.org/java_interop)

Comment: Oh..! I saw this https://github.com/yogthos/clj-pdf#image.

And that's why I didn't suspect!

and I just found out that I have mismatched batman's image to superman's! fans will be angry!

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar And, Corrected some of your mistakes there

Comment: Actually `(new java.util.Date)` is completely correct. In fact, that's what `(java.util.Date.)` gets rewritten to during macroexpansion. It's true that it's more idiomatic to use the dotted form, though. (In the sense that that's what people tend to use in similar contexts. `new` is still used in user code often enough, since it's much more convenient than the "trailing dot" in macros.)

Comment: For what it's worth, I disagree that it's more idiomatic to use the dotted form instead of `new`.  IMHO, `new` is both easier to read (stands out more than a little dot at the end of a word) and doesn't conflate a symbol's name with its purpose at the compiler level.

Comment: @NathanDavis : What's the reason for down voting?